# Does the non default destructor be called when a pointer goes out of reference in cpp 17?

Tags: c++, c++14

```

```
Class A {
....
....
..

/// option A
~A() = default 

/// option B
~A() {
   ///destructor code here
}

}
```

```

Suppose I go with option B where I have defined my own deconstructor, when a pointer pointing to an object holding the above class, I do something like

objAPtr = nullptr;

is the destructor called? or does the above only work with option B

I am using smart pointers here:

```
objAPtr = make_shared<A>();
```

Comment: Why do you think the *form* of the destructor’s definition makes a difference regarding its use?

Answer (score 4):

If you have e.g.

```
A* objAPtr = new A;
objAPtr = nullptr;
```

then no, the object pointed to by `objAPtr` will *not* be destructed. Instead you will lose your only reference to the object, and it will be a leak.

And this has *nothing* to do with what "kind" of destructor you have.

Comment: Sorry I missed to specify, i meant to ask w.r.t shared pointers 
objAPtr = make_shared<A>();

Comment: @ajax_velu That is why it's so important that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us! Then all you should need is [a `std::shared_ptr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). And the "type" of destructor still doesn't matter.

Comment: @ajax_velu - Details about your question belong in your post, not scattered across comments. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52033969/edit) with **all** relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

No, the destructor is not called automatically by setting a pointer to an object to `nullptr`. When and how the destructor is called is not only orthogonal to whether you `= default`-declare it, it's determined by the circumstances and how the memory for holding your instance of `A` was allocated. Example with an `A` instance on the stack:

```
{
    A aInstance;
    A *somePointerToA = &aInstance;

    somePointerToA = nullptr; // aInstance not touched, only the pointer to it.

} // aInstance goes out of scope, now the destructor is called.
```

And when created on the heap:

```
auto *aInstance = new A;
a *somePointerToA = aInstance;

somePointerToA = nullptr; // aInstance again untouched.

delete aInstance; // Now the destructor is called.
```

These semantics change when managing your instance with a smart pointer, that takes care of the destruction. Example:

```
#include <memory>

auto aInstance = std::make_unique<A>();

aInstance = nullptr; // The std::unique_ptr calles A's destructor

auto aSharedInstance = std::make_shared<A>();
auto anotherSharedInstance = aSharedInstance;

aSharedInstance = nullptr; // dtor not called because of anotherSharedInstance
anotherSharedInstance = nullptr; // last pointer to the instance, dtor is called
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the destructor is called on setting the variable to nullptr or doing a reset too:

```
class Test
{
private:
    int m_nID;

public:
    Test(int nID)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructing Test " << nID << '\n';
        m_nID = nID;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructing Test " << m_nID << '\n';
    }

    int getID() { return m_nID; }
};

int main()
{
    // create a shared pointer 
    auto pTest = std::make_shared<Test>(1);
    std::cout << pTest->getID() << '\n';

    // Allocate a Test dynamically
    auto pTest2 = std::make_shared<Test>(2);
    std::cout << pTest2->getID() << '\n';
    pTest = nullptr;
    //pTest.reset();
    std::cout << "before sleep  \n ";
    sleep(5);

    return 0;
} // Test goes out of scope here
```

Running the above the destructor is called on setting it to nullptr.

compile options

```
g++ def_destr.cpp -std=c++14
```